# Premature end of file lex

Tags: apache-flex, bison, lex, eof, lexical-analysis

When I tried to compile it using make keyword it is giving me an error of:

> premature end of file in lex.l file in line no 17.

```
 %option noyywrap
 %{
    #include "grammer.tab.h"
 %}
 name        ([0-9])
 whitespace  [ \r\t\v\f]
 linefeed    \n
 %%
 {name}         { return NAME; }
 ":"            { return COLON; }
 "->"           { return RIGHT_ARROW; }
 "{"            { return LEFT_BRACE;}
 "}"            { return RIGHT_BRACE;}
 ";"            { return SEMICOLON;}
 {whitespace}
 {linefeed}     ++yylineno;
 %%
```

So someone kindly help me.

[image]

Error:-

[image: This is the error that the is shown]

Tail:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVa92.png)

Comment: What's this file look like?

Comment: this error occurred when I compiled the make file

Comment: Yes, yes it did. But saying you have an error, and asking to fix it isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.  If you can provide the error or the Makefile, this would be much more useful.

Comment: here is the address of https://github.com/TheRKP/Compiler

Comment: you can check the make file

Answer (score 1):

You usually get this error from lex (or flex) when the last line is not terminated by a newline.

To resolve the error just put a blank line at the end of the file.

(The same is also true for yacc/bison)

I also note you have a missing action for the pattern `{whitespace}`. I suggest you might try:

```
{whitespace}         ; /* No action */
%%
/* End of the file */
```

Comment: i have uploaded the error image kindly check and please tell the error in the code

Comment: @RahulKumarParihar Have you tried adding the comment as I suggested? Can you do a `tail -4 lex.l` to show the lines at the end of the file have been correctly edited.....

Comment: @RahulKumarParihar Please show me the output I requested.

Comment: I have added your requested output please check